# Method is re-initilizing my variable to 0

Tags: java

I currently have an accounts class having a Deposit method.
Whenever I call this method, it re-initializes the totalamount to zero then it adds the amount added to it thus the total amount is always set to the added amount.

Accounts class:

```
public class Accounts {

double totalAmount;
public Accounts(){
    totalAmount = this.totalAmount;
}
 public double Deposit(double amountAdded) {
    totalAmount+=amountAdded;
    return totalAmount;
}
```

Calling the method in the main:

```
System.out.println("Please enter the customer's account number you want to deposit money for");
int accountNumber = input.nextInt();
while(accountNumber == 0 || accountNumber < 0){
    System.out.println("Please enter an account number greater than 0");
 accountNumber = input.nextInt();
}
try{
for(int i = 0; i < index +1 ; i++){
    if(cust[i].accountNumber1 == accountNumber){
        System.out.println("Please enter the amount you want to deposit");
        double amount = input.nextDouble();
        acc[i] = new Accounts();
        double a = acc[i].Deposit(amount);
        System.out.println(a);
        break;
    }
}
```

let's say the current totalAmount for x person is 100. when calling the method Deposit with additional 300, the method will return 100 and not 400 as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create a new Account instead of using the one from the array.

```
acc[i] = new Accounts();
```

This overwrites the account in the array and the newly created account has a balance of 0.

Comment: Removing it will not solve my issue since without initializing the acc object I wont be able to call the Deposit method.

Comment: Is this the only way you create `Accounts` instances right now? You should probably initialize them together with your customers.

Comment: the customer does not really need an account so creating an account is at a later stage.

Comment: But then the customer had no previous balance and everything works as expected, no? How can a customer without an account have a previous balance?

Comment: got you!
let me try it out.

Comment: worked fine.
I think another workaround can be also implemented - checking if at the index of this customer we do have an account object initialized that I just call the method else I initialize it and then I call the method. (This can be done this im using a hash map between the customer and the account using the same index).